# Max upload size for Google Cloud Run backend using FastAPI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-upload, fastapi, google-cloud-run

According to this query https://stackoverflow.com/a/73723753/14365570 Google Cloud Run limits the upload size for files. Searching the web I found that by enabling the HTTP/2 protocol this limit does not exist. In fact using this code:

```py
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return Response(status_code=200)
```

And by starting the server with hypercorn on the Google Cloud platform, I am able to send even 200MB files.

So reading further it seems that there is no limit for upload size at this point.

However, reading the documentation of FastAPI (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/):

> It uses a "spooled" file: A file stored in memory up to a maximum size limit, and after passing this limit it will be stored in disk.

But when you create a container on Google Cloud Run you don't specify the allocated disk size, only the amount of RAM.

So my question is. If I dedicate a machine with 2 vCPUs and 1GB RAM, and 10 users upload 1 1GB file, what happens to the server? Will it be able to handle the requests?

Comment: Your pattern is not the right one. I recommend to use signedURL and upload to Cloud Storage directly. And then process the files uploaded on Cloud Storage. Cloud Run is not designed to upload and process large file in real time. It does not make sense for API oriented platform

Comment: The temporary file system space is created from memory. That means files consume memory. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#delete_temporary_files

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) helpful

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere My use case is to upload an audio file from the frontend upload it somewhere in the backend and read it from Google Cloud GPU to perform inference on the file, then it is deleted. What approach do you think is most appropriate for this use case? The front end is in flutter, should I from Flutter send the data directly to Google Cloud Storage or Upload data to Google Cloud Storage via Google Cloud Run by exposing endpoint /upload?

Comment: My advice is the same: use signedURL to let the client to upload the file on Cloud Storage. When it's done, run your inference on the platform hosting the model and GPU (Cloud Run does not support GPU for now), and finally send the response back to the client. The deletion can be done asynchronously (with Cloud Storage lifecycle for instance)